# Problem with iPhone push certificate

Tags: java, openssl, ssl-certificate, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using javapns API for push notifications to iPhone.

I made a program which worked fine on windows and I was able to receive push notifications on the device. But when I am deploying that code on the server (Linux), I am getting the following error -

```
java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=127 big
```

I searched the net and figured out that there is something wrong with my .p12 certificate.

Does anyone knows what can be possibly wrong? That certificate, when used in windows, is still working fine and I am able to send the notifications.

Please help.

Comment: It is one of my local linux boxes which i am using for testing, it is not my prod machine. Its an ubuntu machine. Any guess on what particular port do I need to look for ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem , really silly though. I just modified the permission on the .p12 file to 777 and it worked :P. Took me one day to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Would you happen to be in a shared Linux hosting? If I remember correctly the ports used by APN are not open by default.